# a question about getting keyboard stroke on context menu

Tags: winapi, keyboard-events, windows-messages

I am filtering keyboard messages delivered to a specific win32 application by hooking **GetMessage/PeekMessage**, it works fine except for context menu.
For example, when i right click blank area in notepad and press P to paste text from clipboard, i am not seeing GetMessaage(WM_KEYDOWN...) invoked at all. Is there any other apis that are used to get keyboard messages from message queue for context menu?
BTW, for specific reason, i cannot use **WH_KEYBOARD_LL** for this purpose.

Comment: Menu keys are delivered by WM_MENUCHAR.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not seeing a WM_MENUCHAR(0x0120) message retrieved in GetMessage/PeekMessage

Comment: the interesting thing is WH_GETMESSAGE hook can intercept these WM_KEYDOWN/UP messages

Comment: `WM_MENUCHAR` is a sent message, and `WH_GETMESSAGE` hooks do not see sent messages.

Comment: WH_GETMESSAGE only sees posted messages. Use WH_CALLWNDPROC to hook sent messages.

Comment: guys, you are not answering my question, my question is why WM_KEYDOWN/UP is not monitored in GetMessage/PeekMessage hook, I am using Detours hook, not WH_XXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.

I can reproduce this problem on Notepad/Edit control. After discussing with related engineer, it is certain that the menu that appears after pressing the right mouse button and press P can receive `WM_KEYDOWN`, but the `WM_KEYDOWN` message is handled inside the menu and it is converted to other messages. This is why we cannot monitor in `GetMessage`. We don't know the message processing mechanism inside the system menu, but if you are interested, you can draw a menu and test it yourself.

Comment: @herb Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)